# How to run a for loop only x number of times

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I kill multiple processes only X number of time, and not just keep running a loop that keeps to kill them all the time?

Just want to run for loop below 10 times.

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep "helpdax.app" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

Comment: I'm curious if your real goal is to run that loop exactly 10 times? Or at most 10 times? Or until the app is completely killed?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to kill (with the SIGKILL signal (-9) and all its potentially dramatic implications) at most 10 of the processes whose argument list contains `helpdax.app`, you'd do:

```
pgrep -f 'helpdax\.app' | head -n 10 | xargs kill -s KILL
```

Or with `ps`:

```
ps -Ao pid= -o args= |
  awk -v n=10 '/helpdax\.app/ {print $1; if (!--n) exit}' |
  xargs kill -s KILL
```

(though beware some `ps` implementations truncate the `args` list. Generally less so with `ps -o args` than `ps -f`).

As an answer to your literal question (or at least what I understand of it), to exit a loop early in Bourne-like shells, you can use the `break` special builtin.

So to exit after 10 passes in a `for` loop even if all the elements it is meant to loop on have not been processed yet, POSIXly:

```
n=10
for i in ...elements...; do
  ...body of the loop...

  [ "$((n = n - 1))" -gt 0 ] || break
done
```

Or with Korn-like shells (`bash` is Bourne-like, POSIX and Korn-like in this instance):

```
n=10
for i in ...; do
  ...
  ((--n)) || break
done
```